# How defined two replaces in np.where function

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, numpy

I try to compare two excel files with one table in each other. I've succeeded to create a merged table and defined the third column. When the value of first column equal to value of the second column I succeeded to write match in the third column. But when the values are not equal - I want to write 'not matched' but don't know how...

I think i write np.where function wrong, so please help me with it.
I don't want use select/condition python functions

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ff1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\dbokov\Desktop\ff1.csv', index_col=0)

ff0 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\dbokov\Desktop\ff0.csv', index_col=0)

#print(A)
#print(B)

C = pd.merge(left=ff1, right=ff0, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_ff1', '_ff0'])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=C, columns= ['COUNT_ff1', 'COUNT_ff0'])
#print(C)
#print(df)

df['que'] = np.where('COUNT_ff1' == 'COUNT_ff0'), 'match'

print (df)
```

```html
 my result:

                     COUNT_ff1  COUNT_ff0    que
    hina_marketer_id                             
    145130                    3          2  ([],)
    1                         4          4  match
```

Comment: Can you add [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: do you mean something like this ? `df['que'] = np.where('COUNT_ff1' == 'COUNT_ff0'), 'match', 'Not Match')`

Comment: @user3280146, yes, but when i do like this - it makes all values in 'que' column as 'Not Match'....weird

Comment: @jezrael, i don't understand your question

Comment: @DimaBokov - I think not possible test your solution without data, check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @jezrael tnx you, i 've got an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IICU, You just have to complete your [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) accoring to format. Try this.

```
df['que'] = np.where(df['COUNT_ff1'] == df['COUNT_ff0'], 'match','not matched')
```

Comment: When i do like this - it makes all values in 'que' column as 'not matched'....weird

Comment: update the column names properly, try now.

Comment: tnx a lot! Write answer!